# Sending both a file and other POST parameters as AJAX from AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, post

I have an existing POST API, thus:

```
   var data = {
                userName:  $scope.loginData.userName,
                password : forge_sha256($scope.loginData.password),
                XDEBUG_SESSION_START: 'ECLIPSE_DBG'
            };

   var url = HOST + 'api/login.php';

   $http.post(url, data)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
     {
```

I want to upload a file, something like is done in [this Plunk](https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/)

```
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
```

I presume they mean `$scope.uploadFileToUrl`

I need to send some parameters along with the file, to validate that the user has the right to upload and to describe the file.

My question is, how to specify both the file and some other POST parameters that I need to send?

I suppose that I could send the parameters in the header, but that seems wrong. I also code the PHP on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the parameters in the form data.
You can just append them along with the file like

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("param1", param1val);
fd.append('param2', param2val);
fd.append('file', file);
```

I believe this can be treated as multipart form in the PHP on the server side.